# Issue with tomcat bitnami stack for AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, file-permissions, tomcat8, bitnami

I have a bitnami tomcat instance provisioned on AWS. Now, tomcat is started by default as user tomcat while the default user on aws is bitnami. This works for 99% of the cases. However, in my case, I need to access the home folder of the logged in user - in this case bitnami (to be clear I need t access files present in /home/bitnami through a java servlet). I do not want to hardcode the path and instead would prefer getting the home directory through System.getProperty (user.dir). This returns /home/tomcat as tomcat is always started as tomcat.
I tried running catalina.sh as user bitnami after changing catalina.sh permissions - works fine. Now, I want to setup a AMI that starts tomcat using bitnami user. When I add su bitnami -c '/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start' to user data in AWS template, I see that tomcat is started (Checked with ps -ef| grep java). However, no webpages are served (Including the default tomcat page). I have changed directory permissions for work directory as well as logs directory. Catalina.out shows that the server has started. 
Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Changing the service to run under the bitnami account can be a security risk due to the bitnami user has sudo privileges and if something hacks tomcat, he will have admin privileges in your server. I suggest you find a different way to solve this problem, for example by creating a different folder instead of using the home folder of the user so you don't need to change the service configuration.

Comment: In case you really want to make that change, please stop the tomcat service, modify the ctl.sh file of tomcat to use bitnami instead of tomcat and change the permissions of the installation folder. More information about this [here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-start-tomcat-as-a-different-user/58632)